# Is willingly and knowingly touching a person in public without a good reason harassment?

Tags: harassment

**Hypothetical Situation**
Person A: A person with autism.
Person B: A person shooting videos for social media making fun of unsuspecting people like person A.

Person A is enjoying a meal in a restaurant. They're sitting at a table, not in the way of people that need to pass through. Person B sneaks behind person A and tabs person A on the shoulder while trying to keep their presence hidden.

Person A gets a sensory input overload due to their autism. The authorities are involved to deal with the situation. Person A wants the authorities to write a report as person A intends to sue person B for harassment.

**Question**
Does person A have a case in this specific situation?

**Reason for asking**
This is an ongoing discussion between a few people, yet none of us have the required legal knowledge to get to a conclusion. Searching up the definition of Harassment didn't help much either:

*"Harassment is unwelcome conduct that is based on race, color, religion, sex (including sexual orientation, gender identity, or pregnancy), national origin, older age (beginning at age 40), disability, or genetic information (including family medical history)."*

Autism is a disability and touching would be unwelcome conduct. However, person A doesn't know person B suffers for this disability, yet also has no reasonable reason to touch person B as it's just for their own entertainment.

Comment: Harassment is harassment without any of these conditions that you mention. If you harass people just because you think it’s funny, it’s harassment. And as a warning: A few days ago someone in the USA harrased someone to post a Tik-Tok video. The victim carried a gun. The harrasser was shot.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for the warning, but no worries. This is truly a hypothetical situation and not based on any real situation (to my knowledge at least). I thought harassment would require some sort of condition / definition as not to imply that the term is ambiguous (who decides what is and isn't harassment if there's no clear answer other than personal opinion?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

### No it's not [harassment](https://www.alrc.gov.au/publication/serious-invasions-of-privacy-in-the-digital-era-alrc-report-123/15-harassment/criminal-offences-for-harassment/)

> State and territory laws criminalise stalking. These offences often target behaviour amounting to harassment
>
> There are also state and territory offences that capture harassment at work, in family or domestic contexts, and in schools and other educational institutions.

"Harassment" requires a pattern of behaviour which is missing from your example.

### It's probably the tort of [battery](https://www.judcom.nsw.gov.au/publications/benchbks/civil/intentional_torts.html)

> A battery is a voluntary and positive act, done with the intention of causing contact with another, that directly causes that contact: Barker et al at p 36. See *Carter v Walker* (2010) 32 VR 1 at [215] for a summary of the definition of “battery”.
>
> The requisite intention for battery is simply this: the defendant must have intended the consequence of the contact with the plaintiff. The defendant need not know the contact is unlawful. He or she need not intend to cause harm or damage as a result of the contact.
>
> The modern position, however, is that hostile intent or angry state of mind are not necessary to establish battery: *Rixon v Star City Pty Ltd*, above, at [52]. It is for that reason that a medical procedure carried out without the patient’s consent may be a battery.
>
> On the other hand, it is not every contact that will be taken to be a battery. People come into physical contact on a daily basis. For example it is impossible to avoid contact with other persons in a crowded train or at a popular sporting or concert event. The inevitable “jostling” that occurs in these incidents in every day life is simply not actionable as a battery: Rixon at [53]–[54]; *Colins v Wilcock* [1984] 3 All ER 374 per Robert Goff LJ.

Comment: Thank you! That really does makes things a lot more clear.

Comment: If they continue after being told to stop it could become harassment as well though, right?

Answer (score -1):

[south-africa](/questions/tagged/south-africa)

Touching is the equivalent to threatening a persons life, especially if it is unsolicited. If you touch a person self-defence doctrine kicks in and the amount of violence that would it would take to be deemed excessive or unreasonable, increases dramatically.

There may be mitigating circumstances that may effect this value judgment like Dale M mentions.

You probably not going to justify acting in self defense if somebody touches you in a rugby match.

For the most part though the idea that physical interactions are threatening is a valid and reasonable belief that is upheld by the justice system.

Comment: Agreed but aren't mitigating circumstances only relevant in the sentancing stage ? the question seems to be about the guilt stage

Comment: Got a reference to back that up?  It seems pretty extreme and hardly believable that a light tap on the shoulder to politely alert someone that they dropped their keys could trigger a defensible throat punch…